# How to automate sending a password to a program that's waiting for a password

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell script that I use to configure my shell with environment variables associated with the ssh-agent.

```
function eval-ssh-agent
{
  $t0 = (ssh-agent) | Out-String
  $t0 -match 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK=([a-zA-Z0-9.\-\/]*);[\w\d\s;]*SSH_AGENT_PID=([0-9]*);'
  $env:SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$Matches[1]
  $env:SSH_AGENT_PID=$Matches[2]
  ssh-add C:\mykey

}
```

It works just fine, but when PowerShell runs `ssh-add` it always blocks on standard input asking me for my ssh key's password.  I then have to enter the password and hit return.  How can I automate this in the script?

Ideally I would like to do the PowerShell equivalent of the Unix-like piping a string to the program on standard in.  How can this be done?

Comment: Looking and ssh-add linux man page it will always ask password  ( passphrase for a key) from the terminal, and this makes sense. Does this key need to be protected by a passphrase ?

Comment: Indeed, I could just remove the passphrase from the key.  But I'm sure I'll run into the problem again with a different context...

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on how the `ssh-add` executable works.

If it accepts standard input for the password (this seems unlikely), then you could pipe the password to it. This would be quite insecure and definitely not recommended (if it works at all).

If `ssh-add` accepts a command-line argument to specify a password, you could use that (again: insecure).